# How to pass PipelineParameter into AutoMLStep in AzureML Python SDK

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am using AzureML SDK pipeline with AutoMLStep. How can I add PipelineParameter into AutoMLStep configuration? I would like to use it for a definition of max_horizon.
It should work with

> passthru_automl_config=False

but I am getting error

> Message: Unsupported value of max_horizon. max_horizon must be integer or 'auto'

```
max_horizon = PipelineParameter(name='max_horizon', default_value=30)

automl_settings = {
            "iteration_timeout_minutes" : 60
            "grain_column_names": ["COUNTRY_CODE"],
            "time_column_name": "DATE"
        }        

automl_config = AutoMLConfig(task='forecasting',
                             path = "./src",
                             primary_metric=primary_metric,
                             iterations=iterations,
                             max_concurrent_iterations=max_concurrent_iterations,
                             training_data = train_data,
                             label_column_name = label,
                             n_cross_validations=5,
                             compute_target = compute_target,
                             max_horizon= max_horizon,
                             **automl_settings)

trainWithAutomlStep = AutoMLStep(name="experiment_name",
                                 automl_config=automl_config,
                                 passthru_automl_config=False,
                                 outputs=[metrics_data, model_data],
                                 allow_reuse=True)
```

Comment: By the way, there is a type in your code: `max_horizon: max_horizon` should be `max_horizon = max_horizon`

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a response from Microsoft:

> PipelineParameter is currently not supported for use with AutoMLConfig parameters inside of AutoMLStep.
>
> Then, the only workaround in order to use PipelineParameter with
>   AutoMLConfig would be to use AutoML in a PythonScriptStep, which is a
>   similar usage/approach when you use AutoMLConfig with
>   ParallelRunConfig in pipelines (without using AutoMLStep), like the
>   ‘Many Models’ solution accelerator does.

Comment: It's a direct response from the AML product group.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into type-checking issues here. Type `PipelineParameter` is not allowed for `max_horizon`.

As an alternativte: Why don't you strive for a simple `python_script_step` and use the PipelineParameter as an input to that. In the Python-Step file you then define the AutoML routine. This way, you have it all in your hands...

Comment: By the documentation, it looks like passthru_automl_config should be able to handle PipelineParameter. If not, it's a little bit misleading.
-1 You are not able to use AutoML in python_script_step. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-your-first-pipeline).

Comment: Please be specific with the docs. I don't find this passus you mention.

Comment: In these case I wish the code for the azureml-sdk was on GitHub....

Comment: My guess is that the AutMLStep is simply a wrapper for Hyperdrive (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-train-core/azureml.train.hyperdrive?view=azure-ml-py) with some custom output for the Jupyter Notebook widget.

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-steps/azureml.pipeline.steps.automlstep?view=azure-ml-py) is documentation for passthru_automl_config. By this documentation, I supposed that it should work with PipelineParameter.
AutoML step is more like a python pipeline adapter to AutoML run, where HPT is used along with other technics such as feature selection, featurization, etc.

Comment: The answer is partially true. You can't use AutoMLStep inside PythonScriptStep (which is Stefan purpose I suppose) but you can use just AutoMLConfig. See the accepted answer.